# Remove or hide events and friends birthday reminders from Facebook homepage

Tags: facebook-questions

Is there any way to do this?  I don't care to see anyone's birthdays on my homepage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this using an official Facebook method.  You would have to use a third party application.

If you use Firefox then [FeedFilter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/feed-filter/) will filter out Events from your News Feed.